# What is the xpath value of my special case

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is the inspect picture of a webpage,
[image],

as we can see, this value:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Interface Settings - wan')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div
```

is xpath-ed to the yellow-color div part.  Can someone help me how to xpath to its child **path** area in this case ?

So far I have tried such:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Interface Settings - wan')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/svg/path
```

but it does not work for me.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general svg tags can be located as:

```
//*[name()='svg']
```

or

```
//*[local-name()='svg']
```

For your specific case, you could implement the same

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Interface Settings - wan')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div//*[name()='svg']
```

Having said that, I would recommend you to use `relative xpath` rather than `absolute xpath.`